# Redux - How to get form values in its submit handler and call event.preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-router-v4

What I've been trying is to pass values from a form with `Redux-Form` to its `handleSubmit` with event.preventDefault(), so that submitting this form won't change URL.

Chances are that this is to do with `react-router`.

Here are excerpts of my attempt...

```
//form
class SampleForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {      
        return (
          <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>                   
                <Field name="body" component="textarea" />
                <button type="submit" className="btn">Save</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

//container...
class Container extends React.Component {
    handleSubmit(event) {        
        event.preventDefault();
        //How can I get the values from SampleForm?
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SampleForm handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm using `react-router`. Because of this, when I submit the form, the URL gets updated with the submitted values.

(When I was NOT using `react-router`, this didn't happen - I could simply get the values from `handleSubmit()`.)

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to post some of your code - e.g. how you're wrapping the form with redux-form. Could you add this? Also, how are you triggering the submit? Clicking the button or pressing enter?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. React-router doesn't *cause* URL changes, it just handles the request instead of it being passed on to the remote server (i.e. the default form action). `preventDefault()` should block the request from being initiated in the first place, so it shouldn't matter who/what handles the request down the road.

Comment: I only see you using the Field component. Where are you using `redux-form`. Also the `handleSubmit` function is passed to the Redux-form component using  `onSubmit` prop which isn't how you are doing it

Answer (score 1):

So you have your SampleForm component wrapped with Redux-Form. This decorated component should be passed an onSubmit prop from your Container which is the handler. You are passing handleSubmit() as a prop which is conflicting with redux-form's handleSubmit "middleware" that it is trying to do for you.

Change your Container component to pass "onSubmit" in in place of "handleSubmit" as follows:

```
//container...
class Container extends React.Component {
    handleSubmit(event) {        
        event.preventDefault();
        //How can I get the values from SampleForm?
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SampleForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, your Container component should correctly receive the argument "values" as an argument and should be an object of form fields key/values. There is no need to call event.preventDefault() because redux-form's middleware (as I mentioned earlier) does that for you.

So instead of handleSubmit(event), change the event argument to "values" as below:

```
handleSubmit(values) {        
    console.log(values);
}
```